# how to avoid .htaccess duplicate directory names issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to write a .htaccess code for directory. Following is the example, which is I'm trying to get it done.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^member member.php
RewriteRule ^member\/status status.php
```

When I try with `example.com/member` , it works perfectly. And when I try for `example.com/member/status` it shows me member.php wihout any css or JS loading. The ideal output is to show status.php but it showing member.php without CSS and JS files.

Any idea where I'm wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case your first rule should end the match at `member` since it specifically wants to match only that.

```
RewriteRule ^member member.php
```

Should be

```
RewriteRule ^member$ member.php
                   ^
```

Answer (score 0):

please include this on your `<head>` Make sure to change `yourdomain.com` with your domain

```
<base href="http://yourdomain.com" />
```